# Multiple Templates on same page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am creating a wide variety of variable data statements(90+) for the same client.  We print 10K or so of each statement per business day.  Some statements have a particular logo in the upper left of the page, others intentionally omit this.  Some statements have an image and/or text near the bottom, others intentionally do not.  These, along with many others, are added/omitted per statement.

I am not sure if it is possible, but is it possible to 'layer' PDFs on top of each other? If so, I am thinking I could add 'layers' depending on the need of each statement.  Then the resulting 'layered' PDF would become my base document that I could then proceed with adding data to.

Otherwise I am thinking I'd need to create a PDF for each potential scenario.

(BTW, I have tried to conditionally add these items as images directly, but it slows things down quite a bit.)

**Edit**
I have tried to use this code but the final output only shows the last template added.

```
string[] templates = new string[]{
            pdfTemplate
            ,thingsTemplate
        };

        using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(finalTemplate, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        using (iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER))
        using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, filestream))
        {
            document.Open();
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            PdfImportedPage page;
            for (int i = 0; i < templates.Length; i++)
            {
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(new PdfReader(templates[i]), 1);
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            }
            document.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to layer different PDFs on top of each other.

Take a look at the [Layers](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=112) example. We have a file with 4 pages: [layers_orig.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter06/layers_orig.pdf), then we add the 4 pages to a single page: [layers.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter06/layers.pdf).

Well, not exactly the way you would add them, but what you're describing is called [superimposing](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=242) and the [Stationery](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=114) example is more or less doing what you're asking.

We create a PDF, but while creating it, we add some company stationery. This is the stationery: [stationery.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter06/stationery.pdf). This is the final result: [text_on_stationery.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter06/text_on_stationery.pdf).

You can add as many stationery templates as you want in the process.

Comment: any thoughts on why I am not getting my desired results?

Comment: What happens if you change the order in which the templates are added? Maybe you've made your templates in such a way that they are opaque. In that case, you are adding all the templates, but the final one covers all the preceding ones.

Comment: When I change the order of the templates, I do a different template showing. I think that your idea is very much my problem. How do I make templates opaque?

Comment: Your question is wrong. It's not *"How do I make templates opaque?"* The question is: *"How do I avoid that my templates are opaque?"* To answer this question, we should know how you are currently making your templates. My guess is that you are creating pages of which the whole page is a raster image. You should use digital-born PDFs instead. Which tool are you using to create the templates?

Comment: Our client created them using Microsoft Word. They provided us with both the Microsoft Word version, and the Word generated PDF.

Comment: Is there a background color? That could explain why the templates aren't transparent.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  Yes they did have a background color.  For the ones I have MS Word versions of, I was able to remove the background color and then save as PDF.  For the PDFs that we were not provided with the original MS Word versions, I'll need to either 1) Figure how to change the background color of PDFs in Photoshop, or 2) recreate them. Thanks!!